# How do I know in Java 17 which library is still relying on -add-opens or if I can remove it?

Tags: java, java-module, java-17

We recently moved to Java 17. For a few libraries we had to add "--add-opens" parameter to open java internal classes for reflection calls. We wanna get rid of those once Java 17 is widely adapted.

Is there a good way without trial and error to remove those in the future? Any way to get warning again for using it like we had before without downgrading of course?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using Java < 16, you can use the --illegal-access=deny to have the same behavior as Java 16+. Unfortunately, you can't tell in advance if a library needs or not the --add-opens. You can't know for sure if the library will spin bytecodes that will try to use illegal access to JDK classes or if the code that does illegal access is inside an if, for instance.

Comment: Nevertheless, most of the updated libraries do not require the use of --add-opens, though.

Comment: The documentation of those libraries, obviously. If they don’t mention anything about the issue, it’s likely that their authors didn’t care and hence, you can not remove the options. Otherwise, they surely have something like “History: version x.y.z: does not need `--add-opens` anymore”. Or a definite statement which options are (still) required.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the answer. Yet for that you need to know for what library you added a specific add-opens in the first place and if it was added for one or several library?

Comment: Well, yes, when you add an option with such an impact, like `--add-opens`, you should keep track why you added it. But since had done the process of deciding which `--add-opens` to add once, you should be able to use the same process again…